# Is there a social network for webmasters?

Tags: social-media

I am wondering if there is a professional network for webmasters, web developers or SEO?

I have seen many niche networks, but never one oriented to web professionals.

Comment: i have added my answer below was there a particular feature or type of network you had in mind when you posed this question?

Answer (score 3):

I would say in many ways Stack Exchange could be viewed as a "social network". It has many of the features social networks have in that you create a profile, build up reputation, gain badges, chat, sharing to other networks etc.

This could be viewed as similar to the profiles and features you can create on Google+, Facebook, LinkedIn. Stack Exchange also allows you to join niche networks such as Pro Webmasters which are targeted at particular interests.

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages postings other than it's Q&A format, so general discussions, forums, postings of a social net site are missing.  The chat feature does not serve as an adequate substitute.

Comment: I agree with regard to the Q&A format, stack exchange is not what I would describe a traditional social network. Although i still feel the site offers a lot in terms of what the original question asked and community based behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The WebmasterWorld forums are great. As a forum it's sort of a proto-social network, and the quality of content there is genuinely superb. Some of the web's greatest minds assemble there.